# CSS: Active act as hover?

Tags: css, hover

When using tab to navigate my site, is there a way to make an active link act as if the mouse is hovering over it? I have several sub-stylesheets for different colors and a master one for things such as spacing, is there a way that I can make an active element act as css hover without duplicating my hover code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why dont you add it like so:

```
a:hover, 
a.active { color:#000; }
```

And you won't be repeating the same line.

Comment: You should probably add `a:focus` as well, just for completion.

Comment: Hmm, wasn't exactly what I was thinking, but it works! Thanks.